# Requesting an explanation for unexpected behavior of set-car! and define in scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp

While learning scheme commands from the official documentation  https://www.scheme.com/tspl4/start.html#./start:h9

What is going on here:

```
> (define ls1 '((ignored) ignored))
#<unspecified>
> ls1
((ignored) ignored)
> (set-car! (cdr ls1) 'a)
#<unspecified>
> ls1
((ignored) a)
```

This is expected. But when I use a define another `list` which 'looks' like `ls1`, in the following manner, why does `set-car!` replace both occurrences of `ignored` with `a`? I understand that the `define end (cons 'ignored '())` is most likely the reason for the behavior but I can't formulate any explanation for this.

```
> (define end (cons 'ignored '()))
#<unspecified>
> end
(ignored)
> (define ls2 (cons end end))
#<unspecified>
> ((set-car! (cdr ls2) 'a)
#<unspecified>
> ls2
((a) a)
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you had

```
(define end1 (cons 'ignored '()))
(define ls1 (cons end1 (cons 'ignored '())))
(define end2 (cons 'ignored '()))
(define ls2 (cons end2 end2))
```

As is readily seen, `ls2` refers to the *same* entity named `end2` with both it parts, the `car` and the `cdr`.

Quite differently, `ls1`'s two parts are referring each to a different entity - the `car` refers to  `end1` and the `cdr` - to results of another invocation of the same `cons` form:

```
(eq? end2 end2) ;=> #t
(eq? (car ls2) (cdr ls2)) ;=> #t
(eq? (car ls1) (cdr ls1)) ;=> #f
(equal? (car ls1) (cdr ls1)) ;=> #t
```

The `eq?` returning `#t` means the two arguments are actually the same object in memory. So when you alter the contents of a memory-resident object, you *alter the contents of a memory-resident object.* With `ls2`, there's only one location involved, the one referred to by `end2`:

```
(eq? (cdr ls2) end2)       ;=> #t
(set-car! (cdr ls2) 'a)    ; changes `end2` to '(a)
```

Otherwise, each new invocation of `cons` is guaranteed to create and return a *new* location in memory, even if holding `equal?` contents. Hence altering one copy does not affect the other, situated at another place in memory:

```
(eq? (cdr ls1) end1)       ;=> #f
(set-car! (cdr ls1) 'a)    ; `end1` is unchanged
```